# Getting ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: failed to get modem status: -32

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, usb, kernel, usb-hub

Iam using Raspberry pi 3b along with Xbee and Sixfab 3G/4G base sheild. getting

`ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: failed to get modem status: -32 
usb usb1-port1: disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...`
and also getting this `WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_handle_hc_fsm:2462: Unexpected IRQ state on FSM transaction:dev_addr=4 ep=0 fsm=6, hcint=0x00000002`

in syslogs

after running some time all ports are disconnected and reassigned to different ports.
please let us know the solution to overcome this problem.

Rasbian version: `Linux raspberrypi 4.19.66-v7+ #1253 SMP Thu Aug 15 11:49:46 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Xbee: https://www.digi.com/products/embedded-systems/digi-xbee/rf-modules/sub-1-ghz-modules/xbee-pro-xsc

Sixfab: https://sixfab.com/product/raspberry-pi-4g-lte-modem-kit/

Comment: A bit confusing. Are you talking about two shields? (1) Xbee shield, (2) 3G/4G shield? Or is there only one shield, a combo two in one? Perhaps you can give us links to the product datasheet and user manuals.  Are you just setting up and no luck, or running for long time but breaking down just now?

Comment: I have updated the above problem. I am using the xbee with usb adopter to raspberry pi and Sixfab as sheild. We are using the same setup past 1 year but I'm getting this problem in only one RPi

Comment: Thanks for your clarification.  So let me summarize your config. (1) Xbee uses a USB serial cable to connect Rpi on board serial port, or Rpi USB to serial port. talking AT commands (or other API) (2) Lte modem also uses serial AT commands to talk to Rpi. Now please confirm (a) Is the above communication protocol OK, (b) Which side has auto connect/disconnect problems?

Comment: @tlfong01 we are using xbee with xbee adopter connected with usb cable (API operating mode) and Lte modem with USB serial port connected with cable. this problem getting occasionally when xbee receives any data.

Comment: Ah, intermittent errors are too difficult to troubleshoot.  I usually try to swap things, anything I can swap, from PSU, to MCU, wiring, replaceable components, errors due to noise etc are mission impossible for me. Sometimes I even rewrite the program, or switching from SPI to I2C interface. I usually just give up (I am a hobbyist with no project deadlines, just for fun).  Good luck, cheers.